# Removing skype for business using powershell

Tags: powershell, skype-for-business

Hello I am wondering if there is a way to remove skype for business from a bulk of computers using a powershell command? I tried a few things, such as `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\*lync*" -Recurse | Remove-Item`
This commands removes everything that has with skype business to do in the root folder Office16. But it doesn't do the trick as it is not accepted as an official way of removing it from the client computer, and could potentially cause issues.

The other one is `Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.SkypeApp* | Remove-AppxPackage` however this only applies for the default skype app you can install thru the microsoft store.

So if any of you know how I could go about doing this, or if there even is an "official" way of doing it, feel free to leave a reply.

Much obliged.

Comment: Probably `get-package *skype* | uninstall-package`.

Comment: Hello, I have tried this but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Any msi install can be uninstalled like this:

```
uninstall-package 'Microsoft Skype for Business MUI (English) 2016'
```

Comment: I will try this once I have the time, thank you for the reply.